# How to destroy resources in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I have created resources in different workspace in terraform but not able to destroy resource from one specific workspace. Is there any way to destroy resources by specifying workspace? I have switched to that specific workspace while destroying resources but it is still pointing to other workspace state file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first select the workspace with the following command

```
terraform workspace select <workspace_name>
```

Then you can destroy the workspace with

```
terraform destroy -refresh=false
```

if you want to list the workspaces created use

```
terraform workspace list
```